# scanner that may scan both integer and character

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i was trying to do some practice for my school. Please help me because i wanted to get both integers and string in a single scanner. Is it possible?

```
Scanner pal = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Temperature you want to convert: ");
temp = pal.nextInt();
System.out.print("Convert to?: ");
convert_to = pal.next();
```

Comment: temp = pal.nextInt(); is the part that i wanted to make that it may scan both integer and character or even string if possible.

Comment: Please add a sample input and output along with your question. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? your code compiles (assuming that you have initialized `pal` and you have given a type to `temp` and `convert_to`)

Comment: What do you expect a user to enter? A number like _52_ or with type like _52 Celsius_

Comment: Roshana Pitigala yes that's exactly what i wanted. i wanted that a user can input a integer with character like "100 c" or "100 f".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirement properly - you want to parse an input like '12 C'. To do this we can read the input and then parse it based on each word. So in this case the first index will contain the degree and the second index will contain the unit.

```
    Scanner pal = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Temperature you want to convert: ");
    String values[] = pal.nextLine().split(" ");
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
    char unit = values[1].charAt(0);
```

You can then use this for the convert question, thereby we are using just one `Scanner` object to read all the input.

```
    System.out.print("Convert to?: ");
    String convertTo = pal.next();
```

Comment: thanks Nicholas but it's still doesn't work at all. do you have any idea please, but thanks for answering.

Comment: Hmm, I've tested it with giving the input '12 C' and then hitting enter - worked for me. What input are you trying?

Comment: i'm trying to input 100 c

Comment: and i'm using netbeans IDE 8.2.

Comment: I doubt the IDE has anything to do, but your input of '100 c' works fine also. How exactly are you entering the values?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope that helps you with the issue your facing

Comment: he is correct what input he gave is 100 C. thats it and this works perfectly fine

Comment: Enter Temperature you want to convert: 100c
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100c"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at temperatureConversion.main(temperatureConversion.java:13)
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: Put a space between '100' and 'c' so `100c` becomes `100 c`, notice the space in between. You have mentioned the same format in your example!

Comment: but what if i the user don't want to put space between '100' and 'c'?

Comment: That depends on how you design the code. In this scenario it can be problematic (you could parse it but I don't recommend it). I suggest asking the user to first enter the `degree` and then after you validate that, then you can ask for the unit and so on and so forth. Also this answer was with respect to the *current* problem you faced.

Comment: sorry for that space. i forgot to put a space Nicholas K

Comment: That's ok, happy to help. Really appreciate it you could accept my answer.

Comment: @DewormHood in stackoverflow, if someone helps you you should always accept his answer. you can do that with the button below the downvote button.